# Does any part of the kernel on an android device get paged out?

Tags: android, paging

I'm an IT student who's new to these concepts, so be patient with me! I'm writing a paper.

I know in Windows certain parts of the OS that are not critical are paged out. I believe in UNIX none of the kernel is ever paged out. Is any of the kernel paged out in Android?

Comment: Android is Linux.  Go with whatever the answer is on Linux.  Although I suspect the answer is more complicated and depends on what you consider the kernel-  do modules count as the kernel?  Drivers?

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no swap space on current Android devices to which the pages could be swapped.

To see for yourself, run `adb shell cat /proc/meminfo`

You should see that nothing is swapped out:

```
SwapCached:            0 kB
SwapTotal:             0 kB
SwapFree:              0 kB
```

Android does use a [page cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_cache) in RAM, though.